# Increase speed of range().value in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

I currently have a code where, in short, I receive a dictionary of arrays and assign every item of this dictionary to a range of cells. The problem is, as expected, for a large number of cells this gets considerably slow.

The initial code I used was:

```
For i = 1 To clxRtrn.Count
    For j = 0 To UBound(clxRtrn.Item(i))
          Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2 + i, 2 + j).value = clxRtrn(i)(j)
    Next j
Next i
```

Please note that:

```
clxRtrn.Count 'number of rows
UBound(clxRtrn.Item(i)) 'Number of columns
```

I profiled the speed using:

```
Sub DebuggingSpeed()
    Const n = 5
    Dim sngTime As Single
    Dim i As Long
    sngTime = Timer
    For i = 1 To n
        Call SQLite_Query2
    Next i
    sngTime = (Timer - sngTime) / n
    Debug.Print n & " runs in an average of " & Format(sngTime, "0.00") & " seconds."
End Sub
```

For a dictionary of 501 rows with 14 columns (total of 7014 items), I get the following result:

```
5 runs in an average of 0,35 seconds.
```

For a dictionary of 15003 rows with 84 columns (total of 1260252 items), I get the following result:

```
5 runs in an average of 37,32 seconds.
```

Differently than the question asked in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134002/vba-excel-large-data-manipulation-taking-forever), I have to display the results of the dict in the excel sheet (And thus, loop through cells). I don't want to merely manipulate the data in an array, they have to be displayed.

EDIT:
As per [this source](http://www.avdf.com/apr98/art_ot003.html), the idea is minimizing the traffic between the worksheet and the VBA code. I took a different approach. in short, I iterate through the dictionary and write every row into the sheet:

```
 For i = 1 To clxRtrn.Count
    Worksheets("Database").Range(Cells(1 + i, 2), Cells(1 + i, UBound(clxRtrn.Item(i)))).value = clxRtrn(i)
    Next i
```

This sped up the execution considerably:

```
5 runs in an average of 0,03 seconds.
5 runs in an average of 5,32 seconds.
```

Is there still room for improvement on this operation?

Comment: Populate the data into a 2D array and then you can drop that array on the sheet in a single operation.

Comment: @TimWilliams, your suggestion worked greatly already, it reduced operating time in about 3 times. However, it is still pretty slow. Am I able to improve it somehow? Please see edit.

Comment: I'm not sure - do you really have a dictionary of dictionaries as stated at the top of your question?  From your code it looks like a dictionary of arrays.

Comment: This `aKey(i, j) = clxRtrn(i)(j)` is convenient but **much** slower than extracting out clxRtrn(i) into a variable (say `tmp`) and then referencing `tmp` in the inner loop `aKey(i, j) = tmp(j)`.  The difference in performance is about 40-fold.

Comment: Some demo code here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cab2nvkp5601kvk/Performance.txt?dl=0