# VBA Convert Range to Uppercase

Tags: vba, range, cell, uppercase

I would like to convert a Range (from "I5" to the last Cell) to Uppercase in an Excel Table
I calculate the last Cell and try to put it into my code but it always says "object required"
What am i doing wrong?
This is part of my code.

```
Dim rng As String

rng = Range("I5").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)

["I5:" & rng] = [INDEX(UPPER("I5:" & rng),)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square brackets is another universe. They expect a constant and they obey to the formula syntax, not VBA.

With a fixed range, you would go with `= [INDEX(UPPER(I5:I20), )]` (note the absence of `"` around the address). If you try to put `rng` there, it will be understood as a name of an Excel function (that does not exist).

If you want to keep the square brackets approach (I assume to avoid an explicit `For` loop), then try

```vb
Range("I5:" & rng).Value = Application.Evaluate("INDEX(UPPER(I5:" & rng & "), )")
```

Comment: Yes i wanted to avoid the explicit For loop, because it raised my runtime drastically

Comment: @EnginTopuzoglu Apparently you didn't use it [properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50128918/11683).

Comment: I used:
`For Each c In ws.Range("I5:" & Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address)  

c.Value = UCase(c.Value)
Next c
`